# Is it possible to put a resin shed on a slope in the garden?

Tags: shed, gardening

my question is in the title, i've just purchased a new resin shed but I have a sloping ground on my garden. So is it possible to lay it like this or do I have to dig the ground to adjust it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It either should be dug in or supported on the low end or a little of both. You could perhaps let it slope a little if you have to, but it will not let the door or doors act properly after a while. Besides it would look pretty hokey, but that's just my opinion...(insert smiley face here)

Comment: I think i will need to dig a little bit (smiley face) and do things the right way.. thank's a lot for your answer..

Answer (score 1):

More specifically, it's a good idea to avoid placing your shed at the bottom of a slope. Doing so can lead to moisture collecting under or around your shed; which can be a major irritation in the short term, but can also damage your shed, the base of your shed, and/or its contents in the long term.